# Загрузить иконку MFC

Tags: windows, mfc

Не могу загрузить иконку в приложение на MFC: в верхний левый угол и в панели задач. Как это сделать? Уже массу нагугленных вариантов перепробовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В OnCreate главного окна делаешь:

```
HICON hIcon;
hIcon = LoadIcon(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME));
SetIcon( hIcon, TRUE );
```

Будет тебе иконка в главном окне

С иконкой в трее посложнее. Делаешь, например, такую глобальную функцию и определяешь такой идентификор:

```
#define MYWM_NOTIFYICON     (WM_APP+100)

BOOL TrayMessage(HWND hDlg, DWORD dwMessage, UINT uID, HICON hIcon, PSTR pszTip)
{
        BOOL res;

    NOTIFYICONDATA tnd;

    tnd.cbSize      = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
    tnd.hWnd        = hDlg;
    tnd.uID         = uID;

    tnd.uFlags      = NIF_MESSAGE|NIF_ICON|NIF_TIP;
    tnd.uCallbackMessage    = MYWM_NOTIFYICON;
    tnd.hIcon       = hIcon;
    if (pszTip)
    {
        lstrcpyn(tnd.szTip, pszTip, sizeof(tnd.szTip));
    }
    else
    {
        tnd.szTip[0] = '\0';
    }

    res = Shell_NotifyIcon(dwMessage, &tnd);

    if (hIcon)
        DestroyIcon(hIcon);

    return res;
}
```

Потом делаешь в соответствующих функциях OnSize и DefWindowProc главного окна (копирую из своего кода, поэтому у меня диалог)

```
void CFserverDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{

HICON hIcon;

    if(nType==SIZE_MINIMIZED)
    {

    hIcon=AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    TrayMessage(m_hWnd,NIM_ADD,0,hIcon,
        "открыть окно");
    ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

    }
    else
    {
        TrayMessage(m_hWnd,NIM_DELETE,0,NULL,NULL);
    }
    CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
}

LRESULT CFserverDlg::DefWindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    if(message==MYWM_NOTIFYICON)
        if(lParam==WM_LBUTTONUP || lParam==WM_RBUTTONUP )
        {
            ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE);
        }
    return CDialog::DefWindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Вот и все, ребята!

Comment: Спасибо. Иконка заработала и там и там! Просто никто нигде не писал, что это надо в OnCreate делать(( Я в конструкторе окна делал.

Comment: Да, программист в праве ожидать, что это надо делать в конструкторе, но они в эмэфсях не слишком строго придерживались парадигмы ооп, просто сделали обертку для winApi в классах. В библиотеке qt, например, так и сделали, все основные параметры окна через конструктор класса окна, советую на qt делать, объективно лучше и в теории и на практике.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию пути к иконкам прописываются в файлах ресурсов. Надо в обозревателе решений кликнуть по файлу ресурсов (*.rc) или либо указать новый файл с иконкой, либо перейти в текстовый режим и прописать пути вручную. Там может быть что-то наподобие такого:

```
IDR_MAINFRAME           ICON    DISCARDABLE     "res\\Project.ico"
IDR_DEVICETYPE          ICON    DISCARDABLE     "res\\ProjectDoc.ico"
```